# How to get all combinations of 2 columns into 1 data frame in R?

Tags: r

I think an example will make my question clearer

```
c1<- c('A','B','C')
c2<- c(1,2)
```

Desired Output

```
c1  |   c2
____________
 A  |   1
 A  |   2 
 B  |   1
 B  |   2
 C  |   1
 C  |   2
```

Answer (score 2):

a simple solution is the expand.grid function:

```
expand.grid(c1,c2)
```